# Can not generate migration inside Docker container

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, typeorm

I have following `docker-compose.yml`  config

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  postgres:
  image: postgres:13-alpine
  # restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./docker/db/data:${PGDATA:-/var/lib/postgresql/data}
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: root
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    # POSTGRES_DB: db
  ports:
  - 5432:5432
backend:
  build:
    context: backend
    target: dev
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - ./backend/:/src
  command: npm run start:dev
  ports:
  - "5000:3000"
  depends_on:
    - postgres
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: development
    DEBUG: nodejs-docker-express:*
    DB_SCHEMA: postgres
    DB_USER: root
    DB_PASSWORD: root
    DB_HOST: postgres
frontend:
  ports:
    - 3001:3000
  build:
    context: frontend
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
 # volumes:
  #   - ./frontend:/usr/src/app
  #   - /usr/src/app/node_modules
  #   - /usr/src/app/.next

networks:
  portfolio:
   driver: bridge
```

And my scripts in `package.json` are:

```
"scripts": {
"start:dev": "nodemon app.js",
"typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
 },
```

but for some reason when i run `sudo docker exec <backend_container_id> --it typeorm migration:generate -n Entity`
i get

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "typeorm": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

If i run just `typeorm migration:generate`
if get

```
Error during migration generation:
```

Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN postgres
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:69:26) {
errno: -3001,
code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'postgres'
}